# Https 404 Redirection in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Please tell me how to redirect 404 page of following example

https://www.example.co.in/

Answer (score 2):

Create a php page and call name it 404.php and put your redirect urls.

Open .htaccess file and add the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

All done.